# Filter out entire rows if group value is below 10

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to remove rows from a spreadsheet in VBA if the sum total of value exceeds a specific amount.

For example, if I have the following data, names in A1 down and values in A2 down:

[image]

I would like to remove all rows where the total sum of the value in row A does not reach 10 or above in row B, this would leave the following results:

[image]

Thomas = 18 and John = 15 so **all** rows with Thomas and John are kept.

All other rows would be deleted.

Please note that I will always know that the data is in row A and B but I do not know how many rows there will be and need to execute until the first blank cell.

Comment: Hi braX, I don't have any code as I am unable to get this to work, I don't expect the code to be written for me but any suggestions or guidance on functions or ideas or even if it is possible would be good

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro that does what you want? That's a good start if you are trying to learn.

Comment: Use `SUMIF` formula in a blank column to identify the names which do not exceed the criteria and then delete them.

Comment: I had recorded a macro to filter for values under 10 but I could not get it to work for individual lines when it involved grouped values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked. You can see this here:

[image: Excel columns]

```
Sub run()
    Dim rowIndex, countSameRow, sumSameRow As Integer
    sumSameRow = Cells(1, 2)
    rowIndex = 2
    countSameRow = 1
    While IsEmpty(Cells(rowIndex, 1)) = False
      If (Cells(rowIndex, 1) = Cells(rowIndex - 1, 1)) Then
          sumSameRow = sumSameRow + Cells(rowIndex, 2)
          countSameRow = countSameRow + 1
      Else
          If (sumSameRow < 10) Then
              Rows(rowIndex - 1 & ":" & rowIndex - countSameRow).Delete
              rowIndex = rowIndex - countSameRow
          End If
          countSameRow = 1
          sumSameRow = Cells(rowIndex, 2)
      End If
      If IsEmpty(Cells(rowIndex + 1, 1)) Then
          If (sumSameRow < 10) Then
              Rows(rowIndex & ":" & rowIndex - countSameRow + 1).Delete
          End If
      End If
      rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a small note: `Dim i, n, s As Integer` causes only `s` to be dimmed an `Integer` data type, the others will be `Variant`. Either way, rather use `Long` instead of `Integer` to prevent overflow problems (which won't happen on this specific piece of data) =)

Comment: This works well and the code is simple enough for me to learn at my level, thank you! I had not even considered using a loop method, can you advise how I change the values to reference different columns to A and B?

Comment: @user1747021 I don't understand what you mean. Give me an example

Comment: At the moment the names have to be in column A and the values in column B, what vales would I change if it was in columns D and K for example or any other combination?

Comment: @user1747021 take a look at ```Cells(1, 2)``` , it means ```Cells(Row1st, Column2nd)```=> ```cells of row 1, column 2 (column B)```. so cells at row 3, column D will be ```Cells(3, 4)```

Comment: OK I understand that Cells(1, 2) represents Row 1 Column B, therefore if the data is move one column to the right, it should work with Cells(1, 3) but it doesn't and I cannot see how that fails?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203370/discussion-between-user1747021-and-oang-phm).

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree you should write your own code first, but I couldn't help but write some starting code for you. See if the below fits your purpose:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim arr As Variant, rng As Range
Dim dict1 As Object: Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim dict2 As Object: Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Get all of your data form A:B in memory (array)
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:B" & lr)

    'Step through the array and fill up our two dictionaries
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If dict1(arr(x, 1)) <> "" Then
            dict1(arr(x, 1)) = Join(Array(dict1(arr(x, 1)), x & ":" & x), ",")
        Else
            dict1(arr(x, 1)) = x & ":" & x
        End If
        dict2(arr(x, 1)) = dict2(arr(x, 1)) + arr(x, 2)
    Next x

    'Step through our second dictionary and check if value < 10
    For Each Key In dict2.keys
        If dict2(Key) < 10 Then
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Range(dict1(Key)))
            Else
                Set rng = .Range(dict1(Key))
            End If
        End If
    Next Key

    'If any where below 10, this Range object has been filled, so delete it.
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Delete
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't Scripting.Dictionary need a reference?

Comment: @Andreas, do you mean a library reference? This is late binding, so no need.

Comment: Ok my bad! I just thought dictionaries needed a reference.

Comment: @Andreas, Well, early binding could be a good practice because intellisense will pick it up (library is added) and you can refer to methods and properties easily. However, passing it on to others might cause problems. Therefore I don't really mind late binding myself. Personal preference I guess =)

Comment: I copied this and tried to get it to work but it gave me a runtime error but my VBA skills are way too limited to work out why, I also cannot understand most of the code but really do appreciate you posting it and as I progress I can reference this.

Comment: @user1747021, can you tell at what line the error is shown, the code doesn't need much adjustment, only thing to change is the name of sheet1, and just maybe you don't want to start at row 1?

Comment: The error says ActiveX component can't create object and highlights this text Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") - I think this might be because I am running it on a Mac which doesn't support Dictionary object, I will try it on a Windows machine next week!

Comment: Ah yes that must be it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this does work and the error is Mac related, on a Windows machine there is no problem at all. Unfortunately, I can only pick one answer as the correct answer but this is also correct

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method that uses Autofilter and SUMIF to delete the lines.

This assumes there is a header row, if not then add a row first.
It adds a sumif in column C and filters all that is less than 10, then deletes them.
Then removes column C again.

```
Sub filter()

    Range("C1").Value = "Sum"
    Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C2:C" & Lastrow).Formula = "=sumif(A:A,A2,B:B)"


    Range("A2").AutoFilter ' add a filter to table
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<10", Operator:=xlAnd ' filter all below 10

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete ' delete them
    Range("A1").AutoFilter ' remove filter again
    Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Delete ' remove column C
End Sub
```

Comment: Can the one who downvoted comment on why you downvoted a working method?

Comment: Same on my answer @Andreas

Comment: @JvdV Ahh.. It's one of those... Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Here is a vote to counter that behaviour. I don't mind downvotes, but I would like to know the feedback as to why the answer would need be downvoted.